# how to stop downloading a game in itunes?

Tags: itunes-store

i downloaded a car racing game and 23 other games in iTunes , but the download time for the car racing game is 3 hours!how do i stop downloading this game, but not stop download the other 23 games?I have already tried deleting it but i could not.

Answer (score 1):

Just click the downloads icon next to the searchbar. It will open up a list with all the downloads running. Right-click the one you want to stop and select "delete" or "stop" if you want to resume the download later.